# unexplained behaviour of vim or gcc

Tags: c++, regex, linux, vim

I ran this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main ()
{

//    boost::regex fullname_regex ("[A–Z]+[a–z]*, [A-Z][a–z]*");
boost::regex fullname_regex ("[A-Z]+[a-z]*, [A-Z][a-z]*");

string name;
cout << "Enter you full name: " << flush;

getline (cin, name);
if (! regex_match (name, fullname_regex))
{
    cout << "Error: name not entered correctly" << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

which I just copied from somewhere. When I uncomment the commented line (part of the original copy/paste) and comment the next one (typed by myself) the program always rejects the name. Otherwise it works as expected. I am using vim. I did `:set list` to see hidden characters and the lines are identical. I inserted a long comment before the original line in order to move it down, suspecting a disk fault (very old system), but still I got the same error. This is an ubuntu server with no gui, I use putty to do this. I am not accustomed with such problems under linux, if anybody has any idea about what could explain this strange behaviour, please let  me know. Maybe vim still uses some options from the original page, which is [here](http://www.mochima.com/tutorials/strings.html) and is formatted, indeed, but `:set list` does not show them?

Comment: The code is copied from where?

Comment: there is a link in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `-` character in the commented out line is U+2013 *EN DASH*, not the ASCII dash U+002d.

Because of the limited bitmap font I'm using, the Unicode character already stuck out when opening the file, but you can use the `g8` command to print the UTF-8 encoding values of the character under the cursor, or use `:call search('[^\x00-\x7F]')` to locate the next non-ASCII character.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `?[^\x00-\x7F]`?

Comment: @LucasHoepner: Yes, but I have this as part of a mapping, and then it's nice that it doesn't clobber the last search register.

Comment: @LucasHoepner why is this searching backwards?

Comment: The `?...?` search is backwards; use `/.../` for forward searching. Though there are nice blog posts (and the excellent vimcasts series), I still stick to the Vim `:help`. Learn how to navigate and read it; I've been doing this since 2002 :-)

Answer (score 6):

The dashes are not the same. The commented ones are longer and represented by different characters and thus interpreted differently. Common Copy+Paste error.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash

Comment: I was looking for those common website-type characters, but couldn't see any. Well spotted!

Answer (score 1):

When I pasted your code in my text editor, I saw immediately that your first [A-Z] in the commented line is actually using a long dash.

You want a simple dash, which is what you typed.

Comment: Too slow... :-) And indeed, all except one dashes of the commented out line are long.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about the purpose of `:set list`. It is not designed to show "weird" characters in general: only a very small set (tabs, non-breaking spaces, trailing spaces…), see `:help 'list'` for the details.

`set list` wouldn't have helped in this case.

Regular spaces turned into non-breaking spaces is taken care of by `set list` but there are other special characters you should worry about when copy-pasting from the web or a PDF or  mail clients and text processors: `"` are often replaced by `”`, `'` by `’` and so on… The other day I had a long paragraph where all the `'` or `’` where replaced with `¹`. It was easy to spot in that case but could be missed easily in others.